# How to set engine in the PHP Openssl Extension?

Tags: php-openssl

I am using the PHP Openssl Extension by calling openssl_sign() in my code.

My Openssl is configured to use 3 different engines (configuration located in '/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf')

My default engine is set to my custom engine and when I am calling RSA Sign from Command Line (openssl rsautl -sign) it does use my custom engine.

But when using the PHP Openssl Extension it only calls the "regular" Openssl Engine.

I do I force the Extension to use my custom engine ?

Comment: Set OPEN_SSL_CONF_PATH to the path of your openssl.cnf file

Comment: Tried - define("OPEN_SSL_CONF_PATH", "/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf"); Still not working :-(.